# Asp.Net Core - Pass Ckeditor textarea value to controller with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I am using the ckeditor version 4 plugin ...
I want to send ckeditot values ​​to the controller but whatever I do sends a null value!!
I did a lot of searching, tried all the methods on the site, but it didn't work:(
I downloaded the plugin again from the site but it still failed?

Notice: When I use "Id" instead of "asp-for", the value is sent, but I need asp-for....

Html Form :

```
@model Baya.Core.ViewModels.AddProductViewModel
<form id="ProductForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">desc</label>
    <textarea  asp-for="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div> 
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" onclick="return ValidateForm()" class="btn btn-info waves-effect">save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect"
            data-dismiss="modal">
        cancel
    </button>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$(function () {
   /* $('#Description').ckeditor();*/
    CKEDITOR.replace('Description');       
});
function ValidateForm() {       
    let Form = $("#ProductForm")[0];
    let Form_Data = new FormData(Form);
    var descProduct = CKEDITOR.instances.Description.getData();       
    Form_Data.append("Description", descProduct);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/AdminPanel/Product/AddAndUpdateProduct',
        data: Form_Data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {     
            //code
        }
    });
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult AddAndUpdateProduct(AddProductViewModel model)
    {
    //some code
    }
```

This image is also output with breakpoint..
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used This Code:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.Description.updateElement();
var descProduct = document.getElementById('Description').value;
```

Instead of this code:

```
var descProduct = CKEDITOR.instances.Description.getData();
```

It's worked